# How to display link to Product reviews on category list page

Tags: template, ce-1.9.0.1, rwd-theme, category-products

How can you display links to Product reviews on category list page?  So I have something like this:

[image]

I'm working with the new Magento rwd theme and I have the stars appearing fine on the listing page.  I've tried adding the reviews link in **template/catalog/product/list.phtml** with:

```
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
    <?php if ($this->getReviewsCount()): ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->__('%d Review(s)', $this->getReviewsCount()) ?>hello</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

But it is not displaying anything & there are definitly reviews for the products.

Comment: This question is similar; have you looked at it? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6452/show-product-reviews-and-form-in-category-view

Answer (score 3):

you can go to template/review/helper/summary_short.phtml there you can add link for the review count

```
<?php if ($this->getReviewsCount()): ?>
<div class="ratings">
    <?php if ($this->getRatingSummary()):?>
        <div class="rating-box">
            <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $this->getRatingSummary() ?>%"></div>
        </div>
    <?php endif;?>
    <span class="amount"><a href="#" onclick="var t = opener ? opener.window : window; t.location.href='<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>'; return false;"><?php echo $this->__('%d Review(s)', $this->getReviewsCount()) ?></a></span>
</div>  <?php elseif ($this->getDisplayIfEmpty()): ?>
<p class="no-rating"><a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewsUrl() ?>#review-form"><?php echo $this->__('Be the first to review this product') ?></a></p>
```